# Bootstraping Amazon Linux AMI in simple way

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I want to run a python program (a infinite while loop as listener inside) when my instance (Amazon Linux AMI) boots up. I have created a simple shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
python bootstrap.py > bootstrap.log
```

Then I added the name of this script "*`run_service.sh`*"  in my *`/etc/rc.local`* to run each time the instance boots up. But this simple approach seems not working, nothing happens.

I found Amazon Linux AMI is Centos/Fedora based, not Ubuntu. The `cloud-init` option seems not so clear, as I need to make this instance bundled into a customized AMI.

So, how can I do this by avoiding complex settings like puppet/chef, etc in a very simple way?

Comment: If you want the service run on every boot (not just the first) and you are creating your own AMI, then you don't need to worry about cloud-init.

Comment: Adding a command to /etc/rc.local is an ok way to do something on every boot.  There are a lot of things that can go wrong when doing this, especially with a custom program you've written.  E.g., you might need to specify the full path to your script.  Unfortunately, you have not provided enough information for anybody to help debug it.

Comment: This might be better asked on serverfault.com

Comment: Also, if you want to use Ubuntu, why not use an Ubuntu AMI?

Comment: As I said my script name is "run_service.sh", I tried to put it in /ec2-user/home/ and specified the full path name in /etc/rc.local. The shell script runs right if I call it manually, it's not getting executed by rc.local. Do I need to put the shell script and my python file in same folder? Which folder is suitable for that?